# Spark parquet reading

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

Our spark program is reading in parquet files. These files are partitioned by date in a directory like structure (e.g month=201703/day=20170313/). The filenames themselves contain a number which reflects the kafka partition they were from originally (e.g. data.232.parquet). The data of a specific user always ends up in the same partition, so it would make sense if one spark executor would read in all the parquet files of the same partition (to avoid shuffling down the road) across all the dates.

How can we accomplish this ? Maybe we also have to put the partition number in the directory hierarchy ? But even then it's not clear to me how we can tell Spark to use this information.

Comment: where does data resides, HDFS?

Comment: S3. We are using emr to run spark.

Comment: you can use `sc.wholeTextFile`, the problem with it is, one worker will be overloaded if file size is huge and stage processing may be delayed. I would think better not to touch the default behaviour of reading.